# How to change a variable audio file value when calling a function to play the audiofile in Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, events, playback

I am working on a project that when I used a specific keyboard's key a different sound must be played. I have a created a function to play the sound, then I attached an **Event Listener to the DOM** & finally I checked which key has been pressed & play the sound who correspond with the key.

**I am trying to do this by writing DRY code.** How can I change variable sound value when calling the function to play the sound file?

I have a tried changing the `var sound = New Audio('filepath');` before calling the function `playSound()` but it doesn't work.

```
var sound = new Audio('assets/sounds/clap.wav');
// function to play sounds
function playSound() {
  sound.play();
}

// adds event listener & checks keyboard to play different sounds
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 65){
    playSound();
  } else if ( event.keyCode == 83 ) {
    playSound();
  }
  else if( event.keyCode == 68 ) {
    playSound();
  }
  else if( event.keyCode == 70 ) {
    playSound();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the filepath in the conditionals and assign the audio filepath in the function like this:

```
var sound = new Audio('assets/sounds/clap.wav');

function playSound(filepath) {
  sound.src = filepath;
  sound.play();
}

// adds event listener & checks keyboard to play different sounds
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 65){
    playSound('somefilepath');
  } else if ( event.keyCode == 83 ) {
    playSound('somefilepath');
  }
  else if( event.keyCode == 68 ) {
    playSound('somefilepath');
  }
  else if( event.keyCode == 70 ) {
    playSound('somefilepath');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that I didn't include the ```sound.src= filepath;``` line

Comment: Ah okay, I was starting to doubt whether Audio.src was still a thing, no problem!

Comment: do you mind explaining how this solution worked? I tried ```sound = filepath;``` before, instead of ```sound.src = filepath;``` and but it threw me an error. I want to learn :)

Comment: Since you called `new Audio` I figured it must be an object with a property you could set. So I found the DOM Audio on w3 and found [src property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_src.asp). How the source code works, I could not tell you unfortunately, all I know is that the `.src` changes the audio URL ( or retrieves it if you do not assign anything )